# Format chapter's heading

Tags: fonts, sectioning, formatting, chapters, fontsize

I want all my headings to have these characteristics:

1. 12pt
2. Center aligned
3. Bold
4. Times new roman font

But when I write `\chapter{Introduction}`, I can only manipulate the name of the chapter, not the text saying Chapter 1. My final result should be (centered):

**Chapter 1**

**Introduction**

Comment: Give some more information, eg which documentclass are you using?

Comment: This seems to be kind of a special case of the question asked here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-format-the-chapter-heading/11452#11452

You can check there for more sophisticated, but complex ways to change the appearance of headings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your document class (which we don't know) may provide easy ways to customize sectioning headings. In my example, I use the standard `book` class and the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to change the properties of headings.

Notes: Instead of a fixed font size of 12pt, I've use the command `\large` which will produce a size of 12pt given the default standard size of `book` (10pt). Should you insist on a fixed size, I've added a `\sizetwelvefixed` command (to be used instead of `\large`). You also didn't specify if "normal" text should also by typeset in Times; in my example, Latin Modern is used for normal text and Times only for chapter headings.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand{\sizetwelvefixed}{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}

\usepackage{titlesec}
% \titleformat{\chapter}[display]% OLD
%     {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}% OLD
% \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}% OLD
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% NEW
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\large}% NEW
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}% NEW

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, lockstep! I was going crazy with this thing :)

Comment: Thank you for this code.But when I put it in my file the title "Table of content" doesn't change. Could you help me, please?

Comment: @filokalos: You don't mean the "Contents" heading but the chapter entries inside the ToC, right?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. :) Sorry. Maybe it's "Contents" heading. It appears when I give the command `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: @filokalos: Ask a new question (minimal example included), and I'll have a look at it.