# Changing the chapter style

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format the chapter heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-format-the-chapter-heading)

How do you change the style and margins of the chapter title in latex? I'm looking through the style file and can't find anything.

Comment: Please check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-format-the-chapter-heading/11448#11448

Comment: Please note: The modification based also on the documentclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few packages out there you may want to try:

[`fncychap`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap)

[`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty)

if you use the `memoir` documentclass:

[`MemoirChapStyles`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles)

additionally you may find interesting:

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) - package to control TOC entry layout (and hence section titles in TOC, too)

[`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr) - package with commands affecting the header and footer layout; may come handy, if you have the section titles in the header/footer.

The above list includes rather 'user-friendly' packages. However, if you want full control, you will want to try [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec), which is created for advanced users and I assume will make you sweat much more.