# Chapter and TOC in Turkish

Tags: table-of-contents, packages, chapters, languages

When I create a chapter like below, I get **Chapter 1** for example.

```
\chapter{My Chapter Title}
```

But my document is in Turkish so I need to display **Bölüm 1** instead. This is also happening for Table of Contents.

How can I override this?

Comment: You might want to search the site for similar questions such as [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30897/) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/)...

Comment: @percusse I am kind of a newbie on LaTex. Sometimes I don't even know what to search so that's the reason, sorry.

Comment: Not a problem at all. just wanted to give an initial kick in the "doğru yön" ;).

Comment: Turkish is everywhere, ha:) or just on translate.google.com :) thanks !

Comment: let's say we share the same hometown without further spamming here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` to set the language of the document.

borrowed from egreg: `\addtoextrasturkish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{WHATEVER}}` if you are trying to add any other word.

Comment: trying it now...

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks! But is there any way that I can be more specific. For example, what if I would like to display **Contentssss** instead of **Contents**?

Comment: @tugberk With **babel** for Turkish you get *İçindekiler* as the title of the table of contents, which I guess is the right word. If you want to change it, say `\addtoextrasturkish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{WHATEVER}}` in your preamble. Andy may want to add this to his answer.

Comment: @egreg cool. addtoextrasturkish comment belongs to babel package I guess, does it?

Comment: @tugberk Yes, it does. Besides getting the right key words, you get also correct hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg I think the last added command should be `\addto\extrasturkish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{WHATEVER}}`. Note the extra \.