# Chapter titles using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I want my chapter titles to look like as asked in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-format-the-chapter-heading). I have followed the method suggested by "lockstep", that is, using package `titlesec`. It works perfectly fine but here is the question: I want this format for main chapters only and for the rest, that is Contents, Declaration, Index, Bibliography etc I want them centered with normal vertical spaces before and after the title. Pasting the code at the start of Chapter 1 solves the problem partially; it leaves the starting ones (contents, declaration) totally unchanged and applies the same format to Index and Bibliography. Please help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what you have tried till now?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since the lists (ToC, LoF, LoT), the bibliography and index usually use `\chapter*` to format the heading in the document, you can simply use another `\titleformat` command for the `numberless` chapters:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\LARGE\thechapter}{1ex}
  {\titlerule[2pt]\vspace{2ex}}[\vspace{1ex}{\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1ex}
  {\vspace{2ex}}[\vspace{1ex}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{The real numbers}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC

[image]

and another one, of a numbered chapter:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. It did the trick. Many Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with the article class, the ToC title is made with `\section*` instead of `\chapter*`. In that case, the only change from Gonzalo's answer is to swap `\section` in for `\chapter`, and it has the expected effect.