# Change chapter command

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am using the `book` class, is there a way to modify the `\chapter` command to avoid the "Chapter #" above the chapter name and keeping it numbered? Normally I get, for example

```
Chapter 2

The flight of the Bumblebee
```

But I would like only

```
The flight of the Bumblebee
```

Comment: By keeping the numbering, should this appear in the ToC still? And where else? Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use as a point of departure.

Comment: One option would be to use `titlesec` package for the changes. For example see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-format-the-chapter-heading . If you are still having problem, modify the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Werner Yes, the number should appear in the TOC and in the \ref. Gonzalo solution works perfectly. Thank you everybody for the interest and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The flight of the Bumblebee}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without packages, one can redefine `\@makechapterhead` as implemented in `book.cls`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{20\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{The flight of the Bumblebee}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

In the previous example I decreased some vertical space before the title; if one doesn't want this, one can simply (as **Mico** suggests in his comment) `\let` `\@makechapterhead` (controlling formatting for headings for numbered chapters) to be `\@makeschapterhead` (controlling formatting for headings for numbered chapters):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{The flight of the Bumblebee}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Glad to liked my suggestion. :-)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, what is the best way to do it? Since they produce the same result, is there some reason to prefer one approach to the other?

Comment: @Emmet the three are valid approaches; which one to use depends basically on your taste. If you don't feel like adding new packages, the last two approaches are for you; if you don't need any special adjustment for the spacing, the last approach is the quickest way. Using the first approach (using `titlesec`) you don't need to know the internal definitions. All in all, it all boils down to what approach makes you feel more comfortable.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I see, I think I'll use titlesec, thank you very much.