# Formatting Chapter Headings

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am using documentclass book and generating short chapters (one or two pages each).  The chapter headings use too much space.  I want the title at the top of the page, not pushed down.

I reduced some by changing

Chapter 1.

Chapter Title Here

to

1. Chapter Title Here

The code to achieve this:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{DarkBlue}}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
```

but the line is still too far down the page.

I can see the answer in  [How to format the chapter heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/how-to-format-the-chapter-heading/11452#11452)

but I do not understand what to do with the vspace command.  Please excuse my ignorance, but the syntax of latex is really arcane.

Comment: What line talk about you in "but the line is still too far down the page"?

Answer (score 1):

[image: MWE]

If you can switch to the `memoir` class the solution is as easy as use:

```
\chapterstyle{article}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% some code only needed to show margin boundaries and dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\makeatletter
\def\Gm@hrule{\color{blue!50}\hrule height 1pt depth\z@ width\textwidth}%
\def\Gm@vrule{\color{red!50}\vrule width 1pt height\textheight depth\z@}%
\def\Gm@hruled{\color{blue!50}\hrule height\z@ depth1pt width\textwidth}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy text

% The important thing:
\chapterstyle{article} 
% try reparticle, komalike, crosshead, tandh, verville, etc. 
% Use "texdoc memoir" for more options.  

% Optional 

%\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
%\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: i don't know if I can or not.  I will try.  It's so hard to know what will break in latex.